# What's so special about message passing in Smalltalk?

Tags: object, oop, smalltalk, paradigms

I was going through an introduction to Smalltalk.
In C++, the functions declared inside a class can be called by objects of that class, and similarly in Smalltalk a keyword, termed as message, is written adjacent to the name of the object (don't know much but would also like to ask here whether in response to a message a unique method is there to be executed?)

Basically, to my naive mind, this seems to be only a difference in syntax style. But, I wonder if internally in terms of compilation or memory structure this difference in calling holds any significance.

Comment: Don't confuse keywords with messages in Smalltalk. Smalltalk has a tiny number of reserved keywords (depending on the dialect, typically 5 or 6), everything else is messages being sent from object to object in a library you can modify. Even operators like `+` are messages sent to number instances (not primitives, but objects) with the second number as the argument. Smalltalk's syntax is simply, "object message" with the result always being an object (so you can send another message to the result, etc.). Some symbols have special meaning; see http://wiki.c2.com/?SmalltalkSyntaxInaPostcard :-)

Answer (score 28):

The fundamental difference is that in Smalltalk, the receiver of the message has complete control over how that message is handled. It's a true object, not a data structure with functions that operate on it.

That means that in Smalltalk you can send *any* message to *any* object. The compiler places no restrictions on that, it's all handled at runtime. In C++, you can only invoke functions that the compiler knows about.

Also, Smalltalk messages are simply symbols (unique character strings), not a function address in memory as in C++. That means it's easy to send messages interactively, or over a network connection. There is a `perform:` method that lets you send a message given its string name.

An object even receives messages it does not implement. The Virtual Machine detects that case and creates a `Message` object, and then sends the `messageNotUnderstood:` message. Again, it's the object's sole responsibility of how to handle that unknown message. Most objects simply inherit the default implementation which raises an error, but an object can also handle it itself. It could, for example, forward those messages to a remote object, or log them to a file, etc.

Comment: So the basic difference is that Smalltalk is *dynamically typed* (detects type errors at runtime, allowing to handle exceptions) while C++ is *statically typed* (detects type errors at compilation time)?

Comment: No. The basic difference is that a Message is a reified concept in Smalltalk, whereas in C++ the virtual function dispatch is implicit. In Smalltalk you can implement an object that will accept any message with any kinds of arguments (as mentioned in the last paragraph of my answer). There is no way to do that in C++. Error handling is just one of the applications, writing generic proxies for remote procedure calls is another, instrumenting your code for runtime analysis is another, etc.

Comment: @codefrau is right, and it is actually the best way to think of things in Smalltalk - the entire Smalltalk vocabulary is set up for it - you "send" a message to its "receiver" - the message is a thing unto itself - there's a `Message` class you can look at! - the debugger shows you actual message objects, you can get one and save it away to do something with it later, you can forward the Message - whatever it is, whether you understand it or not - to some _other_ object as-is.  (Pay no attention to the man behind the curtain: How it is _implemented_, on a stack, is none of your concern ...)

Comment: What does this mean in practice?

Comment: @user16217248 I'll use Ruby instead of Smalltalk for an example. It's much the same concept, but a more approachable language IMO. In Ruby you can make a mock object which can mock _any_ arbitrary method call (expecting particular values, returning some stubbed result, etc.). This is possible without needing to refactor all your real code to have an `IWidget` interface with a `RealWidget: IWidget` class and a test double `FakeWidget`. Take a look at some of the examples here: https://github.com/freerange/mocha#quick-start This is only possible because the system gives you a way to...

Comment: @user16217248 intercept message passing. You can have a class implement `method_missing`, which is a catch-all for any message passed to it that hasn't yet been defined. This unlocks huge meta-programming possibilities. Mocking is one, but also [distributed objects](https://www.druby.org/sidruby/2-1-understanding-distributed-object-systems.html), [XML builder DSLs](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html), etc. The latter example is interesting: you can write `xml.foo` to get the `xml` builder object to produce a `foo` tag, without there being a `foo` method defined on it.

Answer (score 16):

You *call* a function in C++ because during the compilation time you know which function will be called (or at least you have a finite set of functions defined in a class hierarchy.

Smalltalk is dynamically typed and late bound, so during the compilation time you have no idea which method is going to be evaluated (if one will be at all). Thus you *send* a message, and if the object has a method with that selector, it is evaluated. Otherwise, the "message not understood" exception is raised.

Comment: @JayK I would "promote" this comment to an answer. Would you do that please?

Comment: I think there is a subtle difference beyond the implementation mechanics: when you think in terms of message passing, you don't think in terms of 'global context ownership'. When you call a function, that function now 'owns the world'. Sending a message feels different; you don't expect the object receiving the message to 'take over'.  It's similar to the difference between a program manipulating data structures; conceptually, any function can manipulate any data. This mindset influences design. I think for the better.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia did so. Now it might be too long for some readers, though. ;-)

Comment: @BobNemec Very good point. See also [Object Oriented Programming](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=947961&CFID=906050390&CFTOKEN=97587581) by Tim Rentsch (1982); especially the third paragraph under Messages pg. 54.

Comment: "...*during the compilation time you know which function will be called*...": I fthat were true, C++ wouldn't allow polymorphism (dynamic binding), making it rather useless as OO language.

Comment: @U.Windl you are right. And it's fun to read my 5 year old answers. On the other hand, there are still certain guards that statically typed languages employ to ensure,  that an object will be able to execute a requested method. This gives you some confidence and allows to use the "call" terminology, which is the difference with messaging

Comment: Your old answer is not wrong at all @Uko. Polymorphism is only one of the things that message passing can be used for. But in C++, polymorphic member function calls is the only thing supported. There is no way to write a generic virtual function in C++ that can be called under any name and with any arguments. Which is precisely what true message passing allows.

Answer (score 12):

There are already good answers here. Let me add some details (originally, part of this was in a comment).

In plain C, the target of each function call is determined at link time (except when you use function pointers). C++ adds *virtual functions*, for which the actual function that will be invoked by a call is determined at runtime (dynamic dispatch, late binding). Function pointers allow for custom dispatch mechanisms to some degree, but you have to program it yourself.

In Smalltalk, *all* message sends are dynamically dispatched. In C++ terms this roughly means: All member functions are virtual, and there are no standalone functions (there is always a receiver). Therefore, the Smalltalk compiler never* decides which method will be invoked by a message send. Instead, the invoked method is determined at runtime by the Virtual Machine that implements Smalltalk.

One way to implement virtual function dispatching is *virtual function tables*. An approximate equivalent in Smalltalk are method dictionaries. However, these dictionaries are mutable, unlike typical virtual function tables, which are generated by the C++ compiler and do not change at runtime. All Smalltalk behaviors (`Behavior` being a superclass of `Class`) have such a method dictionary. As @aka.nice pointed out in his answer, the method dictionaries can be queried. But methods can also be *added* (or removed) while the Smalltalk system runs. When the Smalltalk VM dispatches a message send, it searches the method dictionaries of the receiver's superclass chain for the correct method. There are usually caches in place to avoid the recurring cost of that lookup.

Also note that message passing is the only way for objects to communicate in Smalltalk. Two objects cannot access each other's instance variables, even if they belong to the same class. In C++, you can write code that breaks this encapsulation. Hence, message sending is fundamental in Smalltalk, whereas in C++ it is basically an optional feature.

In C++, Java, and similar languages, there is another form of dispatch, called function overloading. It happens exclusively at compile time and selects a function based on the declared types of the arguments at the call site. You cannot influence it at runtime. Smalltalk obviously does not provide this form of dispatch because it does not have static typing of variables. It can be realized nevertheless using idioms such as [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch). Other languages, such as Common Lisp's CLOS or Groovy, provide the even more general *multiple dispatch*, which means that a method will be selected based on both the receiver's type and the *runtime* types of all the arguments.

* Some special messages such as `ifTrue:` `ifFalse:` `whileTrue:` are usually compiled directly to conditional branches and jumps in the bytecode, instead of message sends. But in most cases it does not influence the semantics.

Answer (score 8):

Here are a few example of what you would not find in C++

In Smalltalk, you create a new class by sending a message (either to the superclass, or to the namespace depending on the dialect).

In Smalltalk, you compile a new method by sending a message to a Compiler.

In Smalltalk, a Debugger is opened in response to an unhandled exception by sending a message. All the exception handling is implemented in term of sending messages.

In Smalltalk you can query the methods of a Class, or gather all its instances by sending messages.

More trivially, all control structures (branch, loops, ...) are performed by sending messages.

It's messages all the way down.

Comment: "It's messages all the way down" - yes, but not _objects_ all the way down.  For _that_ you want _Self_.